# Deleting Specific Blob Value Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

i m trying to delete the blob (image) value stored but could not get it how to delete that i have tried this but its not working m successfully deleting the String values i-e video title etc

This is my code where m getting the title of gridview's selected item and image and converting that image to byte array to match that byte array value with DB blob value (correct me if m doing wrong here )

```
gv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.vtitle);
            ImageView img=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tit_img);
            img.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bm=img.getDrawingCache();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            final byte[] img_value = stream.toByteArray();
            final String value=tv.getText().toString();
```

This is how i m deleting the title of selected video item of Gridview here i want to delete the image also that is stored in another table

```
 db.delete("vdetail","title=?",new String[]{value});
```

i tried this for image but its not working

```
db.execSQL("image","thumb=?",img_value);
```

this is how i m creating table

```
db= openOrCreateDatabase("MyDb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists image(thumb blob)");
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists vdetail(title varchar,id varchar)");
```

and here m successfully storing the image title and id

```
public void Save(View view)
{

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0, getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    ContentValues values1=new ContentValues();
    values.put("thumb",bitmapdata);
    values1.put("title",title);
    values1.put("id",id);
    db.insertWithOnConflict("image",null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    db.insertWithOnConflict("vdetail",null,values1,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    Log.d("saving", "m here buddy: ");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

m recieving image (bitmap) from previous activity in intent extra

Comment: what is your database/tables structure? where do you store the blob rowid?

Comment: @pskink please check i have updated my code have a look

Comment: so you are calling `db.insertWithOnConflict("image", ...` but  no using the inserted rowid anywhere

Comment: i just checked it for duplicate values but now m only getting the DISTINCT data and let it storing the duplicate values do i need to put the id autoincrement in image Table and delete the image by id ?

Comment: read first some good tutorial about sql